# Why continue is different between for loop and while loop?

Tags: c++

The difference between continue in a `for` loop and a `while` loop:
In a `for` loop，`spaces` will update if the statement runs to `continue`:

```
int spaces;
for(int i = 0;line[i] != '\0';i++){
    cout << line[i] ;
    if(line[i] == '.')
        break;
    if(line[i] == ' ')
        continue;
    spaces++;
}
```

But in a `while` loop `spaces` would not update:

```
int spaces;
while(line[i]!=='\0'){
    i++;
    cout << line[i] ;
    if(line[i] == '.')
        break;
    if(line[i] == ' ')
        continue;
    spaces++;
}
```

What is the reason?

Comment: Your question is unclear, please edit your question with code examples that explains what you're asking

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue

Comment: Would not perform what?

Comment: Post your code as text not as a link to an image, besides equality is tested using `==`, not `=`, also you're not incrementing `i` in the `while` loop or resetting `i` back to `0` to start at the beginning

Comment: Like the picture，in for loop，when run to continue, the spaces will update，but while loop would not.

Comment: Sorry,my fault.

Comment: Just edit your question and paste the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in for loop，when run to continue, the spaces will update，but while loop would not

This isn't because the `continue` behaves differently, it's because `for` and `while` loops are different.

The [`for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) loop *always* executes the *iteration_expression* after each pass through the body, and before evaluating the condition. That means it's still evaluated after `continue`.

In other news, you're assigning instead of testing in your `if` statements:

```
if (line[i] = ' ')   // changes line[i] to space
if (line[i] == ' ')  // compares line[i] to space
```

and your `while` loop is wrong because it never updates `i` at all.

Answer (score 0):

`Continue` works exactly the same in both cases.
Just think of `continue` as a `goto` to the end of the code block.
E.g. take the following two loops:

```
for (auto i=0;i<100;++i)
   {
   if (i==50) continue;
   std::cout << i;
   }
auto j=100;
while (--j!=0)
   {
   if (j==50) continue;
   std::cout << j;
   }
```

If we replace `continue` with a `goto` to the end of the code block, we get this:

```
for (auto i=0;i<100;++i)
   {
   if (i==50) goto endofforloop;
   std::cout << i;
   endofforloop:
   }
auto j=100;
while (--j!=0)
   {
   if (j==50) endofwhileloop;
   std::cout << j;
   endofwhileloop:
   }
```

So the behavior of `continue` is exactly the same in both cases.

Disclaimer: I am not promoting the use of `goto`, this is just to explain the effect of `continue` :-)